# Finding distance of focal plane in Lumia

Tags: windows-phone-8, camera

I am trying to manually focus the camera on Lumia 520. Though I can focus between a range, I am unable to figure out what that translates in cm/mm. Is there a way to figure that out? Is calibration using measurement of distances the only method?